# script is not running on ajax loaded content in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have a web page in which i have some nested `div` elements forming one complete set which can be loaded dynamically when user clicks load more `button`.

the web page has some script which change the style of the above mentioned `div` element, when the page first loaded.

when the user clicks load more button, ajax call is made and the html received is appended after the above mentioned 'div'element.

the problem is that only raw html is appended to the page, without running the script on it, the result is that only the `div` which is present when the page is first loaded is getting style by the script.

how to get script to run on the dynamically loaded element too?

django views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from printools.models import Images
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    image_set = Images.objects.all()[:3]
    template = loader.get_template('printools/index.html')
    context = {
        'images':image_set,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def ajaxImages(request):
    total_image = Images.objects.all().count()
    n = int(request.POST['nImages'])
    template = loader.get_template('printools/ajaxImages.html')
    data = Images.objects.all()[n:n + 3]
    context = {
        'images': data,
        'n_images':total_image,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

ajax call:

```
        $('#js-single-more').on('click',function (event) {
        console.log('clicked');
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url:'/ajaxImages/',
           dataType: 'html',
           data: {
               'nImages': $('div.cbp-item').length,
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
           },
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               $('.cbp-wrapper').append(data);
           }
       });
    });
```

ajax html:

```
    {% for image in images %}
          <div class="cbp-item {% for category in image.category.all %} {{ category }} {% endfor %}" data-total-images="{{ n_images }}"> <a class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="{{ image.image_file.url }}" alt=""> </div>
            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
              <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                  <p>{{ image.image_name }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </a> </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

initial loaded element:

```
    <div class="cbp-item package video" style="width: 380px; left: 395px; top: 0px;">
    <div class="cbp-item-wrapper">
        <a class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="/media/p2.jpg" alt=""> </div>
            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                        <p>img_2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

notice the `style` attribute is added after script is executed

ajax loaded element:

```
    <div class="cbp-item  poster  identity  video " data-total-images="9">
    <a class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePage">
        <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"> <img src="/media/p4.jpg" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
            <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                    <p>img_4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a> 
</div>
```

script hasn't run on it.

Comment: why don't you write style in a style tag or a css file? that will be applied automatically on ajax loaded content. I think you are writing it inline on the initial content and it is getting replaced

Comment: yeah! css is applied, but the styling is not straightforward  on this element, every element have slightly different styling based on the some logic!

Answer (score 1):

Try chance this:

```
$('#js-single-more').on('click',function (event)
```

For this:

```
$('#element').on('click','#js-single-more',function (event)
```

Where "#element" is an element loaded in the DOM and not created after full page loading (the class ".cbp-item" for example).